# Reimbursement for time-consuming recruitment process?

Tags: recruitment, reimbursement

I am in process of being hired by a company - after 3h of recruitments we have came to agreement, signed it, and I am starting work next month.
Work profile is that I will be 'borrowed' to other companies/clients and work for their project as a developer.

As of now I am being asked to apply to clients projects, each client has their recruitment processes.

- One client after 1.5h recruitment meeting asked me to do a
  homework-project for them which took me about 15h of my own time,
  they did not pick me for their project.
- Another client had a 1h one
  on one recruitment with me today.
- Another client has a booked
  recruitment chat with me tomorrow. This will take another hour or two.

This is a lot of my free time this is taking, is it sensible to expect some sort of reimbursement for time I have spent on this from my to-be employer?

Comment: In my opinion, "I am in process of being hired by a company" contradicts "I am starting work next month" (i.e. how do you know when you are starting if you the hiring process isn't concluded?) which in turn contradicts "I am being asked to apply to clients projects".

Comment: Don't do work for a company short of initial paperwork/studying technologies until you're getting paid by said company.

Comment: @LoremIpsum I have signed work agreement and start working next month. Right now I am being approached by various project managers to join their projects, which in turn requires me to take part in clients-recruitement process to see if I am fitting the project.

Comment: You can certainly ask your future boss. If you are an hourly employee, then you may get paid for these hours. If you are a fixed-salary employee, you may not get paid for them.

Comment: Sounds like either (1) the client successfully conned you into working for 15h for their project, after which they did not need to "pick you" for their project since you had already completed it; or (2) you wasted 15h on a task that wasn't supposed to be that time-consuming, after which the client decided they didn't want someone who could waste time like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This is a lot of my free time this is taking, is it sensible to expect
> some sort of reimbursement for time I have spent on this from my to-be
> employer?

You indicated that you start work next month, so it's unclear why you are discussing potential projects with clients now, and on your own time.

But if "apply to clients projects" is part of your job (and it appears that it is), then yes, you probably should be reimbursed for your time. That might depend on the laws and customs of your locale.

Discuss this with your new manager now. It's probably something that should have been discussed while you were interviewing for this job.

Comment: it is likely that if no client approves the individual then no employment will be forthcoming

Comment: @JoeStrazzere that is correct, even if I do not get a project before starting my work there, I will be 'benched', and search for job will continue while I will be doing some less-important stuff for my employer. Of course if no projects come within first 3 months (how long the first agreement lasts), I might get sacked.